# How can I create a control button for notification with playbackstate value without addAction in Android?

Tags: android, exoplayer

MediaStyle Notification's addAction does not work due to changes in the behavior of apps targeting Android 13 and later.

This is the content of the [Google Doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#playback-controls):

> Starting with Android 13, the system displays up to five action buttons based on the PlaybackState as described in the following table. In compact mode, only the first three action slots will be displayed. For apps that don't target Android 13 or those that don't include a PlaybackState, the system will display controls based on the Action list added to the MediaStyle notification as described in the previous paragraph.

```
mediaSession.apply {
            val stateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
            stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f)
            stateBuilder.addCustomAction("Close","Close",R.drawable.btn_close)
            stateBuilder.setActions(
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE or
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP or
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY or
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS or
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT or
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO
            )
            setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())
            setCallback(object: MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

                override fun onPrepareFromUri(uri: Uri?, extras: Bundle?) {
                    super.onPrepareFromUri(uri, extras)
                    val dataSourceFactory =
                        DefaultDataSourceFactory(this@MusicService, Util.getUserAgent(this@MusicService, "hackers.mp"), null)
                    val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .setTag(
                            MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                                .setExtras(extras)
                                .build()
                        ).createMediaSource(uri)
                    exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
                }

                override fun onCustomAction(action: String?, extras: Bundle?) {
                    super.onCustomAction(action, extras)
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED)
                    removeNowPlayingNotification()
                }

                override fun onPlay() {
                    serviceScope.launch {
                        mediaController.playbackState?.let { state ->
                            updateNotification(state)
                        }
                    }
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
                    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                }

                override fun onPause() {
                    super.onPause()
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED)
                    serviceScope.launch {
                        mediaController.playbackState?.let { state ->
                            updateNotification(state)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onSkipToNext() {
                    super.onSkipToNext()
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_SKIPPING_TO_NEXT)
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_BUFFERING)
                    exoPlayer.next()
                    serviceScope.launch {
                        mediaController.playbackState?.let { state ->
                            updateNotification(state)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onSkipToPrevious() {
                    super.onSkipToPrevious()
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_SKIPPING_TO_PREVIOUS)

                    serviceScope.launch {
                        mediaController.playbackState?.let { state ->
                            updateNotification(state)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onStop() {
                    super.onStop()
                    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED)
                    serviceScope.launch {
                        mediaController.playbackState?.let { state ->
                            updateNotification(state)
                        }
                    }
                    removeNowPlayingNotification()
                }

                override fun onSeekTo(pos: Long) {
                    super.onSeekTo(pos)
                }
            })
        }
```

I added a button as setActions to the media session, but it does not work normally.